Is there a video length limit for generating a spritesheet on google cloud storage?
I am working on a google cloud storage project where I need to generate spritesheets from videos. I've noticed that whenever I generate a spritesheet from a video that is less than or equal to an hour long, the process is successful. However, when the video is longer than an hour, the job fails.
Here are some additional details about my setup:
The videos are in MP4.
I am using nest.js application to generate the spritesheets.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Is there a known limitation on the video length for generating spritesheets, or could this be related to resource constraints or specific settings in the tool I am using?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
{
  "config": {
    "elementaryStreams": [
      {
        "key": "video-stream",
        "videoStream": {
          "h264": {
            "heightPixels": 360,
            "widthPixels": 640,
            "bitrateBps": 2500000,
            "frameRate": 60
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "muxStreams": [
      {
        "key": "dummy-mux",
        "container": "mp4",
        "elementaryStreams": ["video-stream"]
      }
    ],
    "spriteSheets": [
      {
        "filePrefix": "sd-sprite-sheet",
        "spriteHeightPixels": 36,
        "spriteWidthPixels": 64,
        "interval": {
          "seconds": 15
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}



What are you observing that makes you believe there is a size limit?  What is the specific failure you're referring to?  Please edit the question to be more clear what specifically is not working the way you expect.  If you are dealing with code, you should also provide a complete minimal reproducible example that we can use to observe the problem ourselves.
